# Is there a way to test hardware / software in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ram, hardware-test

I’ve been having a lot of connection problems with my laptop running Ubuntu. I’m not sure if it’s the library’s Wifi or something with my machine.

Is there a way to test my hardware (modem, RAM, etc) or my software (Wifi, OS, etc) to determine if it’s a problem on my end?

EDIT:

**@Rinzwind:**

These are the only logs for today:

-rw-------  1 adam adam 27924 Jun 17 15:48  .ICEauthority
drwxr-xr-x 27 adam adam  4096 Jun 17 15:48  .
drwxr-xr-x  7 adam adam  4096 Jun 17 15:53  Desktop
-rw-------  1 adam adam  4229 Jun 17 15:57  .bash_history

**@heynnema:**

Version of Ubuntu: Ubuntu 19.04 - disco

Problem: At library.

Model: Dell XPS laptop

Connection problem: Wifi

What kind of problem: It will initially connect to the Wifi in the library, but will have disconnections randomly. Sometimes the little icon in the top right turns off. At other times the icon is there and I'm able to load certain websites (Codecademy), but others won't work (Google, this one, Youtube.) A lot of time "the connection times out" on some pages, but other pages still load. Rebooting and/or leaving the computer off for 5 or 10 minutes sometimes helps.

This is the result of those commands:

sudo lshw -C network:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v1ImyHAZB4bMPKiG-zDSP6PSrT08_LzF8gRLrmIpM9A/edit?usp=sharing

/var/log/syslog:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LbsbE11CuP8MZKVhJU-O7PE-mA0bJv5nH3OEShU_hCo/edit?usp=sharing

**@waltinator:**

There's about 18,300 lines in that command. These are the lines from today:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z6hlhpQJHbOdSztZ8acInIymAd3SIfKHVxxztVfi_-g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see /var/log. It is there for analyzing issues. As soon as you have a problem check the log file that has the newest change (ls -ltr). Of course next step is to search for the issue on AU and google  and if none come up post a question ;-)

Comment: You have to give us much more information. Version of Ubuntu? Problem at home or work? Make/model #'s of computer and network interfaces (`sudo lshw -C network`). Connection problems on wifi, ethernet, or something else? What kind of connection problem... not connecting... taking too long to connect... disconnections... etc. Check /var/log/syslog around the time of the problem to see if any errors are logged.

Comment: If you're running a supported Ubuntu release `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show log messages about wifi.

Comment: I added some details but I don't really understand what the errors mean. Is there anything I should look for specifically? Or how to repair it?